# Verifying/whitelisting website for Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to make a portal where users can authenticate their Google credentials and then access their Google Calendar by creating and deleting events all via my website. However, I can't seem to find where on the Google Developers Console where to whitelist my site because of this following error:

```
{
"error": "idpiframe_initialization_failed",
"details": "Not a valid origin for the client: https://maxstechandmathsite.azurewebsites.net has not been whitelisted for client ID (my client ID). 
Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."
}
```

The JavaScript code I'm using is in reference to this Github page: https://github.com/gsuitedevs/browser-samples/blob/master/calendar/quickstart/index.html. Besides having to verify my site ownership, the issue may also be having an incorrect client ID or API key. For Google Calendar, I'm assuming you use the client ID and API key for the Google Calendar itself, but would I possibly have to use my Google Sign-In client ID for the OAuth 2.0 authorization? I tried that client ID, but no error message came up in the first place, unlike with the Google Calendar client ID, so I think I'm on the right track. I just can't find any Google docs on this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was right. I did have to use my OAuth 2.0 client ID instead of the Google Calendar client ID generated for me when enabling the Calendar API. Not only that, but I had to use a previous API key I made on the Google Developers Console.